# NSIS: Check that a command is on the PATH

Tags: windows, nsis

How can I check that a command line application is accessible from the PATH with NSIS?

In this particular case, I want to check if `node` is accessible from within the terminal.

I thought about executing `> where node` and comparing the result with `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` however there might be a better way using NSIS functions.

Answer (score 4):

The [SearchPath](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SearchPath) instruction uses SearchPath() to search the system paths for the file.